# flex-basis no está tomando el 40% del contenido padre

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Tengo un contenedor flexible padre de dos elementos, `.phone-element` e `.info-element`.

Al elemento `.phone-element` le estoy poniendo un `flex-basis: 40%;` , y al elemento `.info-element` le estoy seteando un `flex-basis:auto`, el comportamiento que estoy esperando es que el elemento `.phone-element` tenga justamente el 40% del contenedor padre, y el elemento `.info-element` se expanda el resto del contenido disponible.

Estoy consciente de que esto lo puedo lograr seteando un `width: 40%;` en el elemento `.phone-element`, pero quiero entender el porqué de este comportamiento.

```css
.content{
  font-family: Verdana;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
}

  
.content .phone-element{
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-basis: 40%;
    background-color: black;
    aspect-ratio: 561 / 696;
}
  
.content .info-element{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
     <div class=phone-element></div>
      <div class="info-element">
        <div class="text-element">
          <h3 class="title black-element">Some title here</h3>
          <p class="text black-element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores temporibus eum nemo? Placeat natus, corrupti nulla deserunt eius illum. Velit pariatur quod possimus a. Sapiente debitis officiis sint temporibus deserunt!
Pariatur cupiditate perspiciatis ad eveniet minima illum illo, aut molestiae excepturi repellendus culpa dignissimos fugiat et molestias nihil, voluptates error facere nisi. Accusamus voluptates id repudiandae necessitatibus aspernatur iusto sequi.
Sit consequuntur laborum aliquid commodi quae eum pariatur eius doloremque similique facilis cum modi quis corporis, eligendi aspernatur ratione? Accusamus tempora itaque voluptate placeat ipsa ipsum in aliquam molestiae labore.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cards-element"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Franco, en la demo que creaste funciona tal cual debería, es decir, `.phone-element` mide exactamente el `40%` del contenedor

Comment: @Marcos en el pequeño demo que creé efectivamente se estaba comportando como debería, revisando el problema a profundidad encontré que todo radica en el tamaño del texto y la cantidad de palabras que tenga, ya actualicé el demo y ahora si se puede ver el problema que presento... no entiendo muy bien el porqué de este comportamiento, es decir, ¿porqué el elemento de texto ocupa tanto espacio sin importar el 40% que le asigné previamente al elemento del rectángulo negro?

Comment: El tamaño del contenedor está marcado por la propiedad aspect-ratio, no se bien como funciona, pero es la que está marcando el tamaño del div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad `flex-basis` según [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis):

> La propiedad de CSS `flex-basis` especifíca la base flexible, la cual es **el tamaño inicial de un elemento flexible**. [...]

Esto quiere decir que, inicialmente el elemento va a tener el tamaño especificado, pero al ser flexible este puede cambiar según la necesidad.

En tu caso `.phone-element` esta vacío, quiere decir el tamaño de este elemento y de ser necesario puede reducirse.

#### Soluciones:

- Asingnar a `.phone-element` un [`flex-shrink: 0;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)

  Demo:

```css
.content {
  font-family: Verdana;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content .phone-element {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: black;
  aspect-ratio: 561 / 696;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class=phone-element></div>
  <div class="info-element">
    <div class="text-element">
      <h3 class="title black-element">Some title here</h3>
      <p class="text black-element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores temporibus eum nemo? Placeat natus, corrupti nulla deserunt eius illum. Velit pariatur quod possimus a. Sapiente debitis officiis sint temporibus deserunt! Pariatur cupiditate perspiciatis
        ad eveniet minima illum illo, aut molestiae excepturi repellendus culpa dignissimos fugiat et molestias nihil, voluptates error facere nisi. Accusamus voluptates id repudiandae necessitatibus aspernatur iusto sequi. Sit consequuntur laborum aliquid
        commodi quae eum pariatur eius doloremque similique facilis cum modi quis corporis, eligendi aspernatur ratione? Accusamus tempora itaque voluptate placeat ipsa ipsum in aliquam molestiae labore.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cards-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Asingnar a `.info-element` un `flex-basis: 60%;`

  Demo:

```css
.content {
  font-family: Verdana;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content .phone-element {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  background-color: black;
  aspect-ratio: 561 / 696;
}

.content .info-element {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class=phone-element></div>
  <div class="info-element">
    <div class="text-element">
      <h3 class="title black-element">Some title here</h3>
      <p class="text black-element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores temporibus eum nemo? Placeat natus, corrupti nulla deserunt eius illum. Velit pariatur quod possimus a. Sapiente debitis officiis sint temporibus deserunt! Pariatur cupiditate perspiciatis
        ad eveniet minima illum illo, aut molestiae excepturi repellendus culpa dignissimos fugiat et molestias nihil, voluptates error facere nisi. Accusamus voluptates id repudiandae necessitatibus aspernatur iusto sequi. Sit consequuntur laborum aliquid
        commodi quae eum pariatur eius doloremque similique facilis cum modi quis corporis, eligendi aspernatur ratione? Accusamus tempora itaque voluptate placeat ipsa ipsum in aliquam molestiae labore.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cards-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Asingnar a `.phone-element` un [`min-width: 40%;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)

  Demo:

```css
.content {
  font-family: Verdana;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content .phone-element {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  min-width: 40%;
  background-color: black;
  aspect-ratio: 561 / 696;
}

.content .info-element {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class=phone-element></div>
  <div class="info-element">
    <div class="text-element">
      <h3 class="title black-element">Some title here</h3>
      <p class="text black-element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores temporibus eum nemo? Placeat natus, corrupti nulla deserunt eius illum. Velit pariatur quod possimus a. Sapiente debitis officiis sint temporibus deserunt! Pariatur cupiditate perspiciatis
        ad eveniet minima illum illo, aut molestiae excepturi repellendus culpa dignissimos fugiat et molestias nihil, voluptates error facere nisi. Accusamus voluptates id repudiandae necessitatibus aspernatur iusto sequi. Sit consequuntur laborum aliquid
        commodi quae eum pariatur eius doloremque similique facilis cum modi quis corporis, eligendi aspernatur ratione? Accusamus tempora itaque voluptate placeat ipsa ipsum in aliquam molestiae labore.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cards-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```